# Tell JQuery Mobile not to add classes?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, jquery-mobile

I have a Sharepoint application that we're using with mobile browsers. All I'm using from JQuery mobile are the touch event handlers.

JQuery mobile adds classes to the dom to make web pages more mobile friendly, but it's wreaking havoc on Sharepoints automated CSS handling.

Is there a way to tell JQuery Mobile not to mess with the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just the jQM libraries you need as they have decoupled the widgets now:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/2a6c7fc1b982c4308a0450a308f5a66a10e949cf

You can read more about this in the release notes here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

Also you can use native form elements as well:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html