# Using specific elements of jQuery Mobile and not others

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there any way of using jQuery Mobile for only certain features such as toggle on/off switches but not have it take over the entire CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use native form elements:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

Related:

- [Tell JQuery Mobile not to add classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956948/tell-jquery-mobile-not-to-add-classes)

Answer (score 1):

You can set this per element with a `data-role="none"` attribute on the element or bind to the `mobileinit` event like so:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select, input.foo, textarea.bar";
});
```

Notice how you can add classes to the selectors.

From the docs:

> Or, if you'd like to prevent auto-initialization without adding
>   attributes to your markup, you can customize the selector that is used
>   for preventing auto-initialization by setting the page plugin's
>   keepNative option (which defaults to [data-role="none"]. Be sure to
>   configure this option inside an event handler bound to the mobileinit
>   event, so that it applies to the first page as well as subsequent
>   pages that are loaded.

Docs on this can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/docs-forms.html